# Create protection scheme for android audio player

Tags: android, audio, mp3

everyone! 
Me and my team are developing some audio books that we will sell through our android application and our users will also listen them using the in-app mp3 player. We want to find a method (paid or free) to be able to protect our mp3's so the user cannot copy them and play with their own player.

I am aware that someone that is determined can crack anything, but our user targets are not computer geeks, but regular people that want a product that works and occasionally might try to cheat the system

Do you know any system that is easy to implement and can meet our objectives ? 
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> Do you know any system that is easy to implement and can meet our objectives ?

Stream the files from your server (e.g., using RTSP), or store them in internal storage on the device. Those will stop "regular people that want a product that works and occasionally might try to cheat the system" from being able to access MP3 files, which you can then play back using `MediaPlayer` within your own app ("in-app mp3 player").

Comment: For slightly-better-than-average-but-still-not-determined people, basic encryption works. This is for all those root users who could simply copy the contents of any internal storage.